# How do you print all non-empty subsets of an array ordered in Java?

Tags: java, set, subset, combinations

Basically, I already generated all possible non-empty subsets. However, the approach I have taken to find this doesn't print it in the order I want it to. For example, if I input `1 2 3`, I want the program to return:

```
{1}, {2}, {3}, {1 2}, {1 3}, {2 3}, {1 2 3}
```

To clarify, my original approach returns

```
{1}, {2}, {1 2}, {3}, {1 3}, {2, 3}, {1 2 3}
```

Is anyone familiar with a method to order these subsets into the right order? I thought about putting the subsets in an ArrayList of ArrayLists, but then I don't really know how to sort them.

Sample Input:

```
4 5 8
```

Correct Output:

```
4
5
8
4 5
4 8
5 8 
4 5 8
```

My Output:

```
4
5
4 5
8
4 8
5 8
4 5 8
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - please add some sample data for input, and what you have tried.  It's kind of hard to help otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can put them into an ArrayList indeed. Define another ArrayList and loop over through the original ArrayList to check the size of the set. And sort it so that first the subsets of size 1 are added to the newly sorted ArrayList. Then 2, onwards

Comment: How should I determine the order inside these length groups? The problem I had was that I didn't have a good way to sort these independent ArrayLists: how do I order {1 2}, {1 3}, {2 3} without further sorting? Sorry if this seems like a dumb question, I'm kinda new to Java.

Comment: Depends on how you stored the sets? Can you maybe show me this. Because if it is stored in an ArrayList you can use .size().
Or when using a HashSet you can use .size() as well.
You can use HashSets by import this `import java.util.HashSet;`